# Outputing command results to a txt file

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-error, kali-linux

I wrote a small script for running a network vulnerability tool but it doesn't seem to be outputting to the file path I want it to. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

```
     cisco-torch -A 192.168.128.1 -l v > ~/Documents/Network Scanning Logs/ciscotorchlogs/ciscotorchlogs$(date+"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")logfile.txt
```

Ideally the script is supposed to run and create a new file names ciscotorchlogs(date)logfile.txt and put its output in there. I ran the script overnight but I came back this morning and found it had not created any output files.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection was to a file named `Network` in the `Documents` folder because you didn't quote or escape the whitespace. The tokens after the first whitespace will have been passed on as parameters to your command.

With proper quoting, the command would be

```sh
cisco-torch -A 192.168.128.1 -l v > ~/"Documents/Network Scanning Logs/ciscotorchlogs/ciscotorchlogs$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")logfile.txt"
```

Notice how `~` must not be quoted, and how a command substitution within double quotes still gets expanded. (Single quotes would pass the text within the quotes completely verbatim.) Finally, there needs to be a space between the `date` command and its argument.

If you also want to capture standard error, you can add another redirection `2>&1` at the end (again, with a space before it).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed to fix this issue it also helped me find some case sensitivity bugs. I've corrected it and its now outputting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is `~/Documents/Network Scanning Logs` and I suspect those whitespaces are causing issues. You can escape thus:

```
~/Documents/Network\ Scanning\ Logs
```

etc.

Note also that > is redirecting `stdout`. You likely want `stderr` as well, and so I would use

```
> file.txt 2>&1
```

to send `stderr` to the `stdout` stream (and hence be redirected to, say,  `file.txt`)

Comment: ...in particular, you probably created a file `~/Documents/Network`.

Comment: @larsks - My thoughts too

Comment: And you need to quote `"$file"` if it contains whitespace characters, too. (The braces don't help, and don't provide any value here.)

Comment: @tripleee - I wasn't using braces as bash syntax, but merely to indicate a filename being inserted. Not hugely clear, mind. I will amend